# Regex which allow minimum 0.01 and maximum 24 value in price

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I am using `rails` application

I want to allow price validation where `min value : 0.01` and `max value : 24`

Also number start with allow:

- Examples of formats allowed `.23`, `.2`, `1.23`, `0.25`, `5`, `6.3`
- Minimum value of `0.01`
- Maximum value of `24`

What is model validation for this?

Comment: Why not just do number comparison instead of regex.

Comment: Will `validates :price, :inclusion => 0.01..24` do the trick?

Comment: @sshashank124 because of get proper message if error display

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
^(?:0|0?\.(?:0[1-9]|[1-9]\d?)|(?:[1-9]|1\d|2[0-3])(?:\.\d{1,2})?|24(?:\.0{1,2})?)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cZ9mE2)

Comment: And this is why @sshashank124 suggested doing a number comparison in the comments above...

Comment: @awendt Yes, I totally agree that regex is not the proper way to do it :)

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov Thanks. I have used. It is working fine

Answer (score 1):

I would first parse the strings for the any and all floats,

```
[-+]?(\d*[.])?\d+
```

then run comparison operators `(x<=24 && x>=0.001)` on the results to filter the permitted values.

There is no sense trying to do it all in one step with regex unless you are really strapped for resources.